# Get data array from checkbox list in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have multiple checkbox list that can be selected

```
name="campaign_ids"
```

I have a function setup in jquery that looks like this:

```
<script>
$('form#manage_campaigns').submit(function(){
    var formData = $(this);
    $.post(site_url + 'm/affiliates/ajax?action=save_affiliate_campaigns&aid=__aid__', formData, function(data) {
        $('#man_cam_container').fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $('#man_cam_container').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#manage_campaigns').dolPopupHide({});
            }, 2000);

        });
    });
    return false;
})
</script>
```

What I'm trygin to figure out is how to post the array of "campaign_ids" to the URL. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
name="campaign_ids[]"
```

should do it

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this, using [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var formData = {ids: $(this).find('[name="campaign_ids"]').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get() };
```